# Java NIO java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException if the folder is being open in windows explorer

Tags: java, nio

Java nio directory delete gives `java.nio.file.DirectoryNotEmptyException` if the directory is open in windows explorer.
I am using Java 1.7 and below is the code for `DeleteDirVisitor's` `visitFile` and `postVisitDirectory` methods.

```
@Override
public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
    Files.delete(file);
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
}

@Override
public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
    if(exc == null){
        Files.delete(dir);
        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
    throw exc;
}
```

Strangely when i debug the delete call then it doesn't throw any exception but when i run then it fails.
Seems to be a timing issue.
Also, the above API's work 100% if i close the explorer window pointing to the directory being deleted.

Can someone suggest me a work around so that i can get it working 100%.

Thanks,

Comment: You can't. You can't delete a directory that is opened by another process.

Comment: @EJP: As i already mentioned "Strangely when i debug the delete call then it doesn't throw any exception" and hence i assumed it to be a timing issue. In fact while debugging i can see the explorer window pointing to the child directory even when the child directory had been deleted as per the call `File.delete` in `postVisitDirectory`. Its when the parent was deleted then the explorer started pointing to the parents's parent directory.

Comment: But you can't run your program in debug mode in production. I should have stated that this limitation applies on Windows.

Comment: @EJP: Yes, i agree that running in debug is not an option. Actually i was looking for a little bit more information on this limitation and can we have a work around for it or not.